# How to install Tcl dom package in Debian?

Tags: installation, package, debian, tcl

I am using Debian Squeeze. Now I am working with Tcl scripts, and I need to install the Tcl `dom` package. Can anyone tell me how to install it from command line? My Tcl version is 8.5.

Comment: `TclDOM` or `tDOM`? They're competing packages (and `tDOM` is flat-out better, easier to use, and generally what I would always recommend for handling XML and HTML in Tcl). However they're not API-compatible so if code requires `TclDOM` then that's what you need…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package is called [`tdom`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=tdom), so do

```
# apt-get install tdom
```